# Big Sur - Accessibility Zoom not saving last zoom factor

Tags: big-sur, accessibility, zoom

I'm one of those who rely on screen magnification for regular computer usage. I recently updated from Catalina to Big Sur and now there is a very annoying bug with zooming.

How to reproduce:

1. Enable zoom. Screen zooms in.
2. Change the zoom factor with the keyboard shortcut or sliding on the trackpad.
3. Disable zoom. Screen zooms out to 1:1.
4. Enable zoom again. The screen is zoomed in but not to the previously used zoom factor but something less. Almost like the default zoom factor is hard coded.

I have checked "Restore zoom factor on startup" and even tried rebooting the machine more than once. When I reboot it and zoom in for the very first time, it zooms into the level I was using before. But when I enable and disable the zoom, it snaps back to something like 2:1, which for me is way too little.

If I hit the keyboard shortcuts for "Zoom in" and "Zoom ioutn", it goes to my chosen level and back. However, doing this, the zooming is not animated but simply snaps to the last used level. On a 27" iMac, this is uncomfortable since ig can take me a second or two to realize where I am on the screen.

Hope sincerely hope there's a workaround for this. If I need to edit a plist file somewhere to change this "hard coded" zoom level, I'll do that.

Best regards,
Gísli